# Asymptotic for binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Does there exist any asymptotic formula for binomial coefficients ${n \choose k}$ for large $n$ when $k$ is fixed?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) has quite a bit of information on asymptotics and approximations involving binomial coefficients, including

$$\binom{n}k=\frac{n^{\underline k}}{k!}\approx\frac{(n-k/2)^k}{k^ke^{-k}\sqrt{2\pi k}}=\frac{e^k}{\sqrt{2\pi k}}\left(n-\frac{k}2\right)^k$$

for $n$ much larger than $k$, and

$$\binom{n}k=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n\pi/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(k-n/2)^2}{n/2}\right) \left(1+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, you've lost a factor of $k^k$ in the last step of the first approximation.

Comment: @Peter: I have indeed. That was supposed to be $$\frac{e^k}{\sqrt{2\pi k}}\left(\frac{n}k-\frac{1}2\right)^k\;.$$

Answer (score 8):

For large $k$, when $n$ is fixed, the term ${n\choose k}$ is equal to $0$, since it is equal to $0$ for $k>n$.

---

If you fix $k$, then

$${n\choose k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$$

is actually a polynomial (of degree $k$) in $n$, if you expand the expression, since you get $${n\choose k} = \frac{1}{k!}\left(n^k - (1+2+\dots+(k-1))n^{k-1} + \cdots + (-1)\cdot(-2)\cdots (-(k-1))\right)$$